# In Xcode how do we use NSString value to other language using Unicode

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am trying to make an app that converts english to some other language using unicode when typing at runtime. Can you please give me some basic tips on that or any snippet or resources url?

Answer (score 2):

Unicode has nothing to do with your languages whatsoever. To convert say English to Chinese, you need a huge dictionary, ten years of research into the structure of both languages, and then you are ready to go. Translation at runtime for incomplete sentences is nonsense. Language translation doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

Localizing a string while typing may be a challenge, as you should avoid translating word for word, rather than translating by a phrase or sentence. However, I believe what you're looking for is `NSLocalizedString`. I'd suggest first building out the app that translates the text fields input upon pressing a button.

**UPDATE**: I was wrong about NSLocalizedString, which translates pre-defined text in your code to other languages to alleviate the stress of localization/internationalization. Instead, here is an example of an open-source project that uses a Microsoft API to translate text, and is ARC-compatible and ready to be integrated with your application.

Then, you can start to track the user text as it changes, and look for full sentences, and translate them as the user completes each one. Since UIKit isn't guaranteed to be KVO (Key-Value Observing) compliant, you might not be able to track the UITextField's text property, but you could either implement the `<UITextFieldDelegate>` protocol in your View Controller to track the editing property, or you could also use a library like `ReactiveCocoa` to track the text field changes, a la

*In your VC interface*...

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextField *myTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *plainEnglishText;
```

*In your viewDidLoad or another appropriate method*...

```
[[self.myTextField.rac_textSignal filter:^BOOL(NSString *text) {
    // check if a full sentence has been typed since last time,
    // using regular expressions or another method,
    // return YES or NO; the next block will run accordingly.
}] subscribeNext:^(NSString *latestText) {
    // some regular expression again to get last sentence _here_
    NSString *lastSentence = ...;

    // add the last sentence to a string with the full english version
    self.plainEnglishText = [self.plainEnglishText stringByAppendingString:lastSentence];

    // use NSLocalizedString on full plain text _here_
    NSString *localizedString = ...;

    // update text field with new text.
    self.myTextField.text = localizedString;
}];
```

I just wrote that code, but no matter which way you decide to track the changes and update the text field, that snippet, with or without knowledge of the ReactiveCocoa framework, should make enough sense to get an idea of how to go about doing things regardless of how the text field is tracked.

Suggestions welcome. Best.

Comment: hi, thanks very much for the suggestion but i was talking about unicode and you are replying me for localizedstring. For E.g. if I write something in english then change it in some other language using unicode. For localized string i've to make a string file i think and do the stuff. But I want to use unicode.